# Why is this ORDER BY Clause in SQL Statement not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I ran into an old code in an application.  ORDER BY is not working here. From the execution plan, it looks like the ORDER BY is not executed at all.

```
IF(1 = 1)
(
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WHERE   Column1= 'abc' 
)
ELSE
(
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table 
)



ORDER BY Column2
```

I know I can get it to work by refactoring this query like this.
But I am just curious why the ORDER BY is not getting executed in the above query at the first place.

```
IF(1 = 1)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WHERE Column1= 'abc'  ORDER BY Column2
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table ORDER BY Column2
END
```

Comment: `IF` is logical flow operator, it can't be used in single a `SELECT` statement like this.

Comment: Also, SQL Server 2005? Really? That's *long* out of support; and long past time to upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` *is* working, but only for the `ELSE` clause.  SQL Server allows this syntax:

```
(SELECT * FROM dbo.Table )
ORDER BY Column2
```

And that is how the code is being interpreted.  The `ORDER BY` is part of the `ELSE`.  And I should point out that the `IF` condition is true, so it is the `THEN` query that is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `UNION ALL` instead of the `IF`:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WHERE 1 = 1 AND Column1= 'abc' 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WHERE NOT (1 = 1)
ORDER BY Column2
```

(Not here, but IF condition null values might need to be handled
too.)